# SD Card storage vs Android System storage

Tags: android

This is purely a design problem.
When building a video capturing application for Android which storage we should allow the app to store the captured data ?.If you have faced something like this when building your app let do let know what storage choice you decided to use.

SD Card or System Storage

Pros (SD Card perspective)
-The app will not be using the system storage which is good.
-Swapping of saved data will be easy between from one Android device to another.

Cons (SD Card perspective)

-Not all Android users will necessarily have SD Card.Nor it would be fair to ask the user to have a SD Card just for using the application..right ?

Comment: the system stores the videos/images in internal memory if the internal memory is available for use in the phone or if any sdcard is not available. like my phone has 1.5 internal and all recorded videos are stored in it if i don't insert a sdcard, but for phones with no option of internal memory storage for files, user will have to use sdcard for images/videos(not just for your app but for all apps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this option should be dynamic  and not fixed. below are some of my opinion/suggestions for you.

1) Why don't you ask user to input which storage he prefers. You can do it via a dialog box in the app starts(may be once, or as par requirement) **lets user choose this** as you are going to use their phones :)

if you are not agree with 1st here some more suggestions

2) As you mentioned App is **Video Capturing feature**, that implies it would need high/long Storage volume. I would suggest you to go for SD-CARD.

> > Not all Android users will necessarily have SD Card.Nor it would be fair to ask the user to have a SD Card just for using the application..right ?

3) Neither  there is lots of phone with **High Internal memory**. so SD-Card is good option here too, and it is not bad to ask for SD-Card if not available. Many apps does that.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the best option would be best to give the user the option, probably defaulting to SD card if it is available, as it is possible videos could be large and as you mentioned in your post, it is likely the videos would want to be moved somewhere so SD card would be better in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Internal storage is going to be faster to store data to it however, you should give the user the option if they have an SD card.